# Undefined index: title in Unknown on line 0 while add new integration

Tags: magento-2.1.3, integration

I am getting below message

```
Notice: Undefined index: title in Unknown on line 0
#0 /var/www/html/projects/humblechic/vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php(24)
```

on clicking `Add New Integration` under `System -> Integrations`.
How I can debug this to find out exact reason for this.
I have gone through few articles and came to know that it is due to missing title in any of the modules acl.xml 
I want to know exactly which module's acl.xml file missing the title tag. 
Is there any way other than turning off the module one by one and check.

Answer (score 0):

Go into that file

```
vendor/magento/module-integration/Helper/Data.php
```

and add add

```
if(empty($resource['title'])){ print_r($resource);die;}
```

inside foreach

```
  public function mapResources(array $resources)
{
    $output = [];
    foreach ($resources as $resource) {
        $item = [];
        $item['attr']['data-id'] = $resource['id'];
        $item['data'] = $resource['title'];
        $item['children'] = [];
        if (isset($resource['children'])) {
            $item['state'] = 'open';
            $item['children'] = $this->mapResources($resource['children']);
        }
        $output[] = $item;
    }
    return $output;
}
```